# how to insert array values in a single column in mysql with php?

Tags: php, database, checkbox

m dealing with a checkbox selection

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_group[]"  value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_group[]"  value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_group[]"  value="3">
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_group[]"  value="4">
```

here im getting values of checked checkboxes in this array:

```
$ids = array();
foreach($_POST['chk_group'] as $val)
{
$ids[] = (int) $val;
}
echo $ids = implode(',', $ids);
```

if i check 2nd and 3rd checkbox i get [2,3] value in my array `$id`.
the problem is i want to store these values separately in db table column

table is:

`product_attribute`

- id
- a_id

i want to insert the values from the array in the column a_id

id ------     a_id
1   -------      2
2   -------      3
how can i use the insert query to store this data in mysql table??

Comment: you can JSON_ENCODE these values and then save in one column in mysql, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Where you have

```
implode(',', $ids)
```

Replace it with your SQL.  For example:

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO product_attribute (a_id) VALUES (" . implode('),(', $ids) . ")");
```

I would leave your casting loop as that sanitizes the data.

Comment: thanks for your help! but it dont work for me.. im new to this maybe m not doing it right!

Comment: Then update your question with your new code and showing any errors you receive.